# Comma separated value & wildcards in mysql

Tags: mysql, wildcard, csv

I have a value in my database with comma separated data eg.

```
11,223,343,123
```

I want to get the data, if it match a certain number (in this example it's number 223).

```
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_value IN
('223', '223,%', '%,223,%', '%,223')
```

I thought I could use wildcard for it, but with no luck. Any ideas of how to do this? Maybe it's better to do this using PHP?

Comment: Don't use comma separated columns in a database: **It's that bad:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: If you really can't avoid it, use **`FIND_IN_SET()`** function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: I am using the value to exlude sertain "Post ID's". So for the pages I want tp exclude I just type in the ID's of these pages. Would it be so much better to have a new row for each ID I want to exclude? (I am new to MySQL)

Comment: Read the answer by Bill Karwin on that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing stuff in a comma separated list usually is a bad idea, but if you must, use the [`FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('223',wp_postmeta.meta_value)
```

If you can change your database and normalise it, you would get faster results. Create an extra table that links meta_values to your primary_id in your table.

Comment: You might want to add that you need to check if the value is > 0. i.e. `WHERE FIND_IN_SET('223',wp_postmeta.meta_value) > 0`

Comment: @omarello: no, MySQL does this for you. `WHERE 0` is false and doesn't return results, `WHERE 1` (or higher than 1) is true and will return rows. `WHERE NULL` is `NULL` and so doesn't return rows. The query works as stated.

Answer (score 1):

The `wp_post_meta` table is designed to hold loads of values, and for that simple reason (and because of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), you should not never comma seperated lists as values in databases.

If you absolutely must use it this way, there are some mySQL functions, one being [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

Comment: Thanks Jan. Nice reputation you got there. I don't want to break it ;)